# Azure DevOps - Drop folder empty in React build for Azure YAML pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to implement the YAML pipeline into my project; however, the current code does not give not output into the drop folder. I don't have any subfolders. The project is at the root. Any ideas? I have seen somewhere that in the scripts part I need pushd to specify directory and popd at the end.

Project structure:

[image]

I have seen this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QbmLxfRCt38&t=406s but how would I specify the root folder.

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You archive `Build.BinariesDirectory` which is:

> The local path on the agent you can use as an output folder for compiled binaries.
>
> By default, new build pipelines are not set up to clean this directory. You can define your build to clean it up on the Repository tab.
>
> For example: c:\agent_work\1\b.
>
> This variable is agent-scoped, and can be used as an environment variable in a script and as a parameter in a build task, but not as part of the build number or as a version control tag.

And usually npm produces `dist` directory located nera to your code. So this is for sure wrong path to archive.

Your step should be rather

```
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: 'src/dist'
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
```

bit to be sure please add temporary step like

`- bash: ls src`

after `'npm install and build'` step.

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- bash: ls src
  displayName: 'Check directories'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: 'build/static'
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true


- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
```

Comment: Could you update your answer to show what the complete pipeline would look like including your - bash scripts.

Comment: So can you explain, why the Drop folder is empty? and where your code will fix it?

Comment: You archived empty folder. And tjat's it.  You archive `rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'`, me `    rootFolderOrFile: 'src/dist'` however it all depends on your app, how build step is configured. If tehre is no changes you should have it in `dist` folder.

Comment: Ran the pipeline based on your code and it failed: with error `##[error]Error: Archive creation failed for archive file: /home/vsts/work/1/a/526115.zip`

Comment: That's fine - and what we have here in logs `'Check directories'`?

Comment: code: 12 
stdout:  zip warning: name not matched: dist
zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -r /home/vsts/work/1/a/526115.zip . -i dist)

Comment: ##[error]Archive creation failed for archive file: /home/vsts/work/1/a/526115.zip

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236906/discussion-between-krzysztof-madej-and-sole).

Comment: I edited answer. We should use `build/static`.